# Emacsql string query with space

Tags: whitespace

My sqlite database has columns which consist of TEXT objects containing spaces. I'm new to both emacs and programming, and while I want to use emacsql for reasons, it's crucial that I can select on string objects containing spaces.

e.g. `(emacsql db [:select * :from table1 :where (= name "John Q Doe-Deer")])` 
doesn't work, and neither does `'John\ Q\ Doe-Deer`: they both returned `nil` even though an analogous query works in command-line sqlite. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> Any readable lisp value can be stored as a value in EmacSQL, including numbers, strings, symbols, lists, vectors, and closures. EmacSQL has no concept of "TEXT" values; it's all just lisp objects. The lisp object nil corresponds 1:1 with NULL in the database.

All values (except `nil`) are stored as text and then `read` back. So `(a b)` would be stored as `"(a b)"` and `"John Q Doe-Deer"` as `"\"John Q Doe-Deer\""`.

Also see https://github.com/skeeto/emacsql/issues/13.

Comment: I tried that, but it still didn't work.